# Is it possible to set a breakpoint in the Perl debugger without modifying the source?

Tags: perl, debugging

I'm stepping through someone else's code to find what's breaking mine under a certain, untestable (don't ask me why the test framework gives different results from live use, that's what I'm trying to figure out) circumstance. Each time I'm getting a little further into the code before I crash, is there any way I can set the breakpoint without modifying the source code? so I don't have to next, step, next, next, next, each time? or modify the source each time. Also take into consideration that I have to step through multiple files, as these programs make extensive use of libraries, and the bug itself appears to be within one of those libraries. So e.g. I know I need to continue executing until I hit line number of file. Also the libraries are loading libraries, I was at least 3-5 libraries deep the last I checked.

*note: I'm new to debuggers in general*

Comment: Have you read [perldebug](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html)?

Comment: @ephemient I've read through [perldebtut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebtut.html#Stepping-through-code) because perldebug was a little comprehensive for me at this point. since I don't really even know the basics of what I'm doing. I even found parts of that a little confusing, so I may have missed something important.

Comment: @ephemient if you would like to tell me what section exactly in perldebug I should be reading that would be appreciated.

Comment: you might want to try the ptkdb debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [`b`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html#b) command in the interactive Perl debugger, which can be used to set future breakpoints.  Or maybe the [`c`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html#c) command, which works like GDB's `until` if given an argument.

You can also automatically set certain breakpoints every time you start the debugger with [`afterinit`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html#afterinit) in `.perldb`.  Or use the [`R`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html#R) command which restarts the debugger (and the program being debugged) while keeping breakpoints and other information.

Comment: I clarified my question a bit. part of my problem is that I'm not sure how I could jump to a line, or sub that doesn't exist yet, or how I would test for that.

Comment: @xenoterracide: You can set a breakpoint for when a file is loaded with `b load filename`.  Once you've hit that breakpoint, you can set further breakpoints within that file.  Or you can use `require` to force a file to be loaded *now*.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a combination of the **b** command, the **f** command, the contents of **%INC**, and the **c** command to quickly navigate through your code.

**c**  lets you continue execution till you reach the given line. This allows you to easily jump forward to an arbitrary point.

If you want to break at a particular point in a module, look at the entry for that module in **%INC** (the key will be **'Some/Module.pm'** if the module was **Some::Module**). The value for that key is the file that the module was loaded from. If the module hasn't been loaded yet, you can **use** it at the debugger's command prompt, then look in **%INC**.

Once you have the file that contains the code you want to set the breakpoint in, do **f filename** to switch the debugger's **l** (list) and text search commands (**/** and **?** - forward and back, respectively) to look at that file, then set the breakpoint you want and **c** to reach it.